# Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread - multi-threading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, session

I have a java-spring web application and I use some external libraries which I don't have access to. 
At one of the flows, I create a new thread and use this external library. I get an exception:
[image: Exception]

Is there any possible way to overcome this exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem as this, and came across with: https://bekce.github.io/replacing-session-scope-with-thread-scope-in-spring-framework/

"here is a problem with session scoped beans when your application also needs other integration points other than web servlets".

I then used the custom scope = "thread" from sping's [SimpleThredScope.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html)

In bean config, something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
      <property name="scopes">
          <map>
              <entry key="thread">
                  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
              </entry>
          </map>
      </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="testA" class="com.concretepage.A"  scope="thread" />
```